# VSCode Extension webview external html and css

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a vscode extension and the goal is to display a webview with a extern html and css.
Loading and setting the html works but unfortunately the css won't get load.

Creating webview,loading html and setting :

```
var resultPanel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel("test", "TestWebView", vscode.ViewColumn.One, {});
    fs.readFile(path.join(context.extensionPath,'src','languageMenue.html'),(err,data) => {
          if(err) {console.error(err)}
          resultPanel.webview.html = data;
      });
```

This works, inside the html the css get loaded like that :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

The css is in the same folder as the html (inside the src folder of my the extension project)

What am I missing? Why the css won't get load?

Comment: Same for me, not working as simple CSS link. Have you found a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read this [Controlling access to local resources](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#controlling-access-to-local-resources)

And note about `localResourceRoots` as below code:

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
        'catCoding',
        'Cat Coding',
        vscode.ViewColumn.One,
        {
          // Only allow the webview to access resources in our extension's media directory
          localResourceRoots: [vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'media'))]
        }
      );
```

You can edit the line to:
`localResourceRoots: [vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'your/relative/location/here/in/your/extension/path'))]`

Answer (score 5):

To make this work you have to specify the absolute path where the `css` file is stored.

i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/dir/of/theme.css">
```

Since `vscode` suggests to use `secure content policy`, the way to achieve dynamic loading of the path is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{styleSrc}}">
```

where `{{styleSrc}}` is binded as:

```
const styleSrc = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(vscode.context.extensionPath, '/path/to/dir/of/theme.css')).with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' })
```

or with the `asWebviewUri` API as:

```
const onDiskPath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(vscode.context.extensionPath, '/path/to/dir/of/theme.css'))
const styleSrc = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(onDiskPath)
```

where `panel` is the one created with `vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(...)`

For more info see: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#loading-local-content

Comment: const onDiskPath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(vscode.context.extensionPath, '/path/to/dir/of/theme.css'))
const styleSrc = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(onDiskPath)  This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Read through the vscode webview guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview

Specifically pay close attention to the "Loading local content" section: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#loading-local-content

There are special rules for how to load external content for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the css filename in your html file with `styleUri.toString()`, just binding with `{{styleSrc}}` does not work.

```
const htmlPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this._extensionPath, '/res/html/index.html'));
var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlPathOnDisk.path).toString();

const stylePathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this._extensionPath, '/res/css/styles.css'));
const styleUri = webview.asWebviewUri(stylePathOnDisk);
html = html.replace('filename_of_css_file_in_your_html_file.css', styleUri.toString());

// continue for any other resources, e.g. scripts

webview.html = html
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to figure things out so here's a more verbose solution using registerWebviewViewProvider which is setup slightly differently.

I want to point out that localResourceRoots should contain directories not specific files (Took me awhile to figure that out).

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{pathCSS}}">
    </head>
    <body>
```

typescript:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const provider = new customViewProvider(context.extensionPath);
}
class customViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
    public static readonly viewType = "decomp_webview";
    private _view?: vscode.WebviewView;
    private extensionUri: string;
    public webview: vscode.Webview | undefined;
    constructor(
        private readonly _extensionUri: string,
    ) {
        this.extensionUri = _extensionUri;
     }

    public resolveWebviewView(
        webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
        context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext,
        _token: vscode.CancellationToken,
    ) {
        this._view = webviewView;
        console.log("PATH: "+this._extensionUri);
        webviewView.webview.options = {
            enableScripts: true,
            localResourceRoots: [
                vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.extensionUri, "/src")),
            ]
        };

        let html = fs.readFileSync(vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.extensionUri, "src/ui.html")).with({scheme: 'vscode-resource'}).fsPath, "utf-8");

        const pathToCSS = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.extensionUri, 'src/ui.css'));

        html = html.replace("{{pathCSS}}", String(webviewView.webview.asWebviewUri(pathCSS)));

        console.log(html);

        const updateWebview = () => {
            webviewView.webview.html = html
        };

        setInterval(updateWebview, 1000);
```